# Android - upload image to server

Tags: android, image, upload

I know there is a lot to find but I still can't seem to fix my problem.
Here's the code I have to upload an image from an imageview.
The imageview has mImageUri, this is from the Aviary Editor that I use in this app.

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void doFileUpload(){
    String selectedPath = "";
    selectedPath = getPath(mImageUri);
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    DataInputStream inStream = null;
    String lineEnd = "rn";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary =  "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;
    String responseFromServer = "";
    String urlString = "http://cliniclowns.boxhost.me/upload.php";
    try
    {
     //------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(selectedPath) );
     // open a URL connection to the Servlet
     URL url = new URL(urlString);
     // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
     conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
     // Allow Inputs
     conn.setDoInput(true);
     // Allow Outputs
     conn.setDoOutput(true);
     // Don't use a cached copy.
     conn.setUseCaches(false);
     // Use a post method.
     conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
     conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
     conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
     dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );
     dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
     dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name:\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + selectedPath + "\"" + lineEnd);
     dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
     // create a buffer of maximum size
     bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
     bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
     buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
     // read file and write it into form...
     bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
     while (bytesRead > 0)
     {
      dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
      bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
      bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
      bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
     }
     // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
     dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
     dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
     // close streams
     Log.e("Debug","File is written");
     fileInputStream.close();
     dos.flush();
     dos.close();
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException ex)
    {
         Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
    catch (IOException ioe)
    {
         Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
    }
    //------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
    try {
          inStream = new DataInputStream ( conn.getInputStream() );
          String str;

          while (( str = inStream.readLine()) != null)
          {
               Log.e("Debug","Server Response "+str);
          }
          inStream.close();

    }
    catch (IOException ioex){
         Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
    }
  }
```

Sometimes i get a NullPointerException and sometimes my app just freezes and crashes.
Any has a solution?

EDIT

Logcat output:

```
06-20 13:22:52.724: I/feather-launcher(21073): onCreate
06-20 13:22:52.785: D/dalvikvm(21073): GC_CONCURRENT freed 26K, 46% free 2938K/5379K,     external 5132K/5599K, paused 2ms+2ms
06-20 13:22:52.804: D/feather-launcher(21073): Pictures folder: /mnt/sdcard/Pictures
06-20 13:22:52.804: I/feather-launcher(21073): onResume
06-20 13:22:52.934: I/feather-launcher(21073): onCreate
06-20 13:22:52.954: D/feather-launcher(21073): Pictures folder: /mnt/sdcard/Pictures
06-20 13:22:52.954: I/feather-launcher(21073): onResume
06-20 13:22:52.954: D/PhoneWindow(21073): couldn't save which view has focus because the focused view com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@2b0018e0 has no id.
06-20 13:22:53.395: I/feather-launcher(21073): onResume
06-20 13:22:56.465: D/feather-launcher(21073): pickRandomImage. total images: 265, position: 60
06-20 13:22:56.465: D/feather-launcher(21073): /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/100ANDRO/DSC_0054.JPG
06-20 13:22:56.465: D/feather-launcher(21073): image uri: /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/100ANDRO/DSC_0054.JPG
06-20 13:22:56.555: D/feather-launcher(21073): width: 400
06-20 13:22:56.669: D/dalvikvm(21073): GC_CONCURRENT freed 147K, 46% free 3087K/5639K, external 5936K/7413K, paused 2ms+2ms
06-20 13:22:56.804: D/feather-launcher(21073): image size: 320x180
06-20 13:22:58.394: D/AndroidRuntime(21073): Shutting down VM
06-20 13:22:58.394: W/dalvikvm(21073): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2aac8578)
06-20 13:22:58.405: E/AndroidRuntime(21073): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-20 13:22:58.405: E/AndroidRuntime(21073): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-20 13:22:58.405: E/AndroidRuntime(21073):    at com.project4.LaatsteTabActivity.getPath(LaatsteTabActivity.java:254)
06-20 13:22:58.405: E/AndroidRuntime(21073):    at com.project4.LaatsteTabActivity.doFileUpload(LaatsteTabActivity.java:262)
06-20 13:22:58.405: E/AndroidRuntime(21073):    at com.project4.LaatsteTabActivity.access$5(LaatsteTabActivity.java:260)
06-20 13:22:58.405: E/AndroidRuntime(21073):    at com.project4.LaatsteTabActivity$4.onClick(LaatsteTabActivity.java:128)
06-20 13:22:58.405: E/AndroidRuntime(21073):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2552)
06-20 13:22:58.405: E/AndroidRuntime(21073):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9229)
06-20 13:22:58.405: E/AndroidRuntime(21073):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-20 13:22:58.405: E/AndroidRuntime(21073):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-20 13:22:58.405: E/AndroidRuntime(21073):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-20 13:22:58.405: E/AndroidRuntime(21073):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
06-20 13:22:58.405: E/AndroidRuntime(21073):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-20 13:22:58.405: E/AndroidRuntime(21073):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-20 13:22:58.405: E/AndroidRuntime(21073):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
06-20 13:22:58.405: E/AndroidRuntime(21073):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
06-20 13:22:58.405: E/AndroidRuntime(21073):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post your logcat output containing the exception, stack trace, etc.

Comment: Maybe the cursor is null

Comment: I don't know what the Cursor does to be honest, how can I prevent the cursor from being null?

Comment: You can't prevent the cursor from being null. It can return null in certain cases. You need to check for that.

Comment: Check that `mImageUri` is a URI of the form `content://...` as per the documentation for `ContentResolver.query()` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#query%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String%29